# This form has expired. Please refresh and try again

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I see this is a time-honored problem...

I am using **Freeform 4.1.3** on **EE 2.9.2**. This has been a stable solution for a long time. I have changed nothing with the system. I have been successfully collecting data as recently as last week. I have created a couple of new forms that are essentially clones of forms that still work. And yet I get the dreaded error.

Have tried two browsers, one with no related history. Source code shows hidden fields for both XID and crf_token values. I have cleared the cache. I cannot turn off caching, getting the "Cannot connect to Dummy, using File driver instead" error message.

I see other threads with solutions that work some of the time for some of the people, but I hate to go twisting knobs when the current configuration has been working fine.

Any help? Simple code:

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form_name="council_nom"
    required="first_name|last_name|email"
    notify_user="yes" 
    user_notification_template="default" 
    user_email_field="email"
    notify_admin="yes" 
    admin_notification_template="default_template" 
    admin_notify="webmaster@4sonline.org" 
    return="http://www.4sonline.org/prizes/carson/got_it"
}

    <h3>Nominated by</h3>
    <label>First name:  </label>
    {freeform:field:first_name}

    <label>Last name:    </label>
    {freeform:field:last_name}

    <label>Email:    </label>
    {freeform:field:email}

    <label>Institution:    </label>
    {freeform:field:institution}

    <h3>Nominee</h3>
    <label>First name</label>
    {freeform:field:nominee_first}

    <label>Last name:    </label>
    {freeform:field:nominee_last}

    <label>Email:    </label>
    {freeform:field:nominee_email}

    <label>Institution:    </label>
    {freeform:field:nominee_institution}


    <label>Rationale (limit 2,000 words)</label>
    {freeform:field:rationale}


    <p>Not so fast!<br/>
      {freeform:captcha} <br>
      If you are not a robot, please type the text above into this box:
      <input type="text" name="captcha" /> <br/>
    </p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using ce_cache module. You need to **escape** the cache for form so it can get fresh CSRF token and XID for each refresh.

Try:

```
{exp:ce_cache:escape}
    {exp:freeform:form
        form_name="council_nom"
        required="first_name|last_name|email"
        notify_user="yes" 
        user_notification_template="default" 
        user_email_field="email"
        notify_admin="yes" 
        admin_notification_template="default_template" 
        admin_notify="webmaster@4sonline.org" 
        return="http://www.4sonline.org/prizes/carson/got_it"
    }

        <h3>Nominated by</h3>
        <label>First name:  </label>
        {freeform:field:first_name}

        <label>Last name:    </label>
        {freeform:field:last_name}

        <label>Email:    </label>
        {freeform:field:email}

        <label>Institution:    </label>
        {freeform:field:institution}

        <h3>Nominee</h3>
        <label>First name</label>
        {freeform:field:nominee_first}

        <label>Last name:    </label>
        {freeform:field:nominee_last}

        <label>Email:    </label>
        {freeform:field:nominee_email}

        <label>Institution:    </label>
        {freeform:field:nominee_institution}


        <label>Rationale (limit 2,000 words)</label>
        {freeform:field:rationale}


        <p>Not so fast!<br/>
          {freeform:captcha} <br>
          If you are not a robot, please type the text above into this box:
          <input type="text" name="captcha" /> <br/>
        </p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

    {/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:ce_cache:escape}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I am not using ce_cache. Inserting the suggested code yielded a template error.

Again, why would other forms work and this one not?

BTW, no wait time is required to trigger the expiration. I am never able to submit.

Comment: You mentioned that you get error:  I cannot turn off caching, getting the "Cannot connect to Dummy, using File driver instead" error message. This error only occur when you are using caching.

Comment: If that is the case, I should be able to clear the cache and submit a form, correct? This is not the case.

Comment: Try copy the form in brand new template. Run that new page and submit the form.

Comment: Same result. Form expired.

Comment: Add this variable in config.php `$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';`

Comment: Works! Any reason i can't live with this solution?

Comment: For some reason your form not generate proper CSRF token. You need to figure it out. Try going to security settings and change the website and cp session types to something different and try every time new incognito browser by submitting form. http://prntscr.com/hvtdvh

Comment: Ha! I set both to Cookies only and got the error message in the control panel. Also find this in the developer log: 
Deprecated function generate_xid() called in system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/addon_builder/addon_builder.php on line 3009.
From template tag exp:freeform:form in site/test_nom.
Deprecated since 2.8. Use the CSRF_TOKEN constant instead.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using a version of Freeform that is not compatible with the version of ExpressionEngine you're using. [Freeform 4.1.4 makes a compatibility update for EE 2.8+](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/legacy/freeform-4/change_log/#v4.1.4), which changed the way CSRF handling works (specifically, EE changed things from `XID_TOKEN` to `CSRF_TOKEN`).

The version of Freeform you're using is also over 4 years old. The latest version available for Freeform 4.x for EE2 is [Freeform 4.2.5](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/legacy/freeform-4/change_log/#v4.2.5). I would recommend you update to this version to resolve this issue (and several other issues).

If you're using the Pro version of Freeform, you will have access to this update inside your [Solspace account](https://solspace.com/account/software). If this is the free version of Freeform, you'll need to [contact Solspace support](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/support/) for the updated version (select "Account" from the **Product** menu in support form).